# Scrolling on one axis blocks the other

Tags: javascript, html, css, tauri

I'm making a simple file viewer in Tauri framework (Just simple HTML and CSS). Because of long files I can't just put the content of the file to the `<pre>` element that I use to display the visible lines. So I call the rust backend with parameters of what lines are visible inside of a viewport to render just those. To simulate the scrolling i use `<div>` scaled to math the size that will the text have if will be displayed normally in one piece. While the `<pre>` is fixed to the viewport and can't be moved with.

Now when i scroll on one axis I'm unable to scroll on the other unless i wait a couple of seconds. This bug gives me no errors in the debugging console.

Code in charge of updating the lines:

```js
addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (last_number_of_lines_above_viewport !== get_lines_above_viewport()) {
        lazy_redraw();
        last_number_of_lines_above_viewport = get_lines_above_viewport();
    }
});

function lazy_redraw() {
    if (loaded_file) { //Catches no file was loaded
        invoke('lazy_read_lines', {file_path: loaded_file.file_path, filter: filtered_tab_lines.slice(get_lines_above_viewport(), get_lines_above_viewport() + get_lines_inside_viewport())})
            .then((message) => { //Just returns string of lines inside a specified viewport
                document.getElementsByClassName("file")[0].innerText = message;
            }
        );
    }   
}
```

`<pre>` element css style:

```css
.file {
    margin: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* Sometimes one line is slightly below the viewport, causing an extra scrollbar */

}
```

---

I thought the problem is caused by different lines length but after putting spaces at the end of the shorter ones to make their length equal i don't get any difference.

I have also tried updateing the viewport using the `requestAnimationFrame()`:

```js
let animationFrameId = null;

addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (animationFrameId === null) {
        animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(scrollHandler);
    }
});

function scrollHandler() {
    if (last_number_of_lines_above_viewport !== get_lines_above_viewport()) {
        lazy_redraw();
        last_number_of_lines_above_viewport = get_lines_above_viewport();
    }
    animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(scrollHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was that the `<pre>` element that displays the text lost focus when user clicked outside, than the browser didn't listen to scrolling on that element until I click back in it.

I fixed it by returning focus to that element when lost, I know that this solution isn't optimal but it works fine in my case.

```html
<pre onfocusout="document.getElementById('file').focus();" id="file" autofocus></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, have you considered throttling scrolling events?

```js
// Set up the throttler 
const throttle = (fn, delay) => { 
  // Capture the current time 
  let time = Date.now(); 
 
  // Here's our logic 
  return () => { 
    if((time + delay - Date.now()) <= 0) { 
      // Run the function we've passed to our throttler, 
      // and reset the `time` variable (so we can check again). 
      fn(); 
      time = Date.now(); 
    } 
  } 
} 
 
// Here's a dummy function that we want to throttle 
function runOnScroll(){ 
  console.log('function fired!'); 
} 
 
// We can use this like so: 
window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(runOnScroll, 1000)); 
// This will run `runOnScroll` at most once per second.
```

I'd also recommend check how other editors do the rendering. There's a common approach to do Canvas based rendering (with WebGL) and another one is commonly used in vscode IDE - [monaco editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor)